# Parsing unstructured, "human-friendly" application log files

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing, logging

I need to parse several hundred megabytes of application logs which kinda look like this:

```
2016/05/26  13:07:48 UTC - 15:07:48   Rear gear disengaged
2016/05/26  13:08:13 UTC - 15:08:13   RMCB : Backend in unknown position
2016/05/26  13:08:14 UTC - 15:08:14   OVERPRESSURE ALARM STATUS : no alarm
2016/05/26  13:08:14 UTC - 15:08:14   PRESSURE STATUS : Equipment Off
2016/05/26  13:08:14 UTC - 15:08:14   OVERPRESSURE LINE STATUS : line failure
2016/05/26  13:08:14 UTC - 15:08:14   FILTER EQUIPMENT STATUS : Equipment Off
2016/05/26  13:08:14 UTC - 15:08:14   FILTER LINE STATUS : line failure
2016/05/26  13:08:15 UTC - 15:08:15   RMCB : Backend closed
2016/05/26  13:08:20 UTC - 15:08:20   OVERPRESSURE ALARM STATUS : value=3
2016/05/26  13:08:20 UTC - 15:08:20   OVERPRESSURE ALARM STATUS : alarm Overpressure
2016/05/26  13:08:20 UTC - 15:08:20   PRESSURE STATUS : OK
2016/05/26  13:08:20 UTC - 15:08:20   OVERPRESSURE LINE STATUS : OK
2016/05/26  13:08:20 UTC - 15:08:20   FILTER EQUIPMENT STATUS : OK
2016/05/26  13:08:20 UTC - 15:08:20   FILTER LINE STATUS : OK
2016/05/26  13:08:20 UTC - 15:08:20    [COMMANDER] open wizard view
2016/05/26  13:08:20 UTC - 15:08:20    [DRIVER] open wizard view
2016/05/26  13:08:20 UTC - 15:08:20    [OP2] open wizard view
2016/05/26  13:08:28 UTC - 15:08:28   Acknowledge Alarm : alarm Overpressure
```

As you can see, they don't have any fixed structure besides a timestamp, but I need to get individual key/value properties from them.

For example this line:

```
FILTER EQUIPMENT STATUS : OK
```

It's a **status** event related to the **equipment** of a **filter**, so I need to parse it to the following key/value pairs:

```
EventType: Status
SourceContext: FILTER (could also be OVERPRESSURE etc.)
StatusType: EQUIPMENT (could also be LINE)
StatusValue: OK (could also be line failure, if it's a line status)
```

and so on. The same goes for a line like this:

```
[COMMANDER] open wizard view
```

Here we have:

```
EventType: Instruction
Sender: COMMANDER
Instruction: open wizard view
```

I don't need to have hundreds of different types or something, a simple type with e.g. a fixed event type and a dictionary of key/value pairs is fine, but I need to find a way to correctly identify the individual *properties* and map them into said dictionary.

---

I first tried using Regex capture groups, but besides massive performance issues, I ended up with hundreds of different patterns of which some of them were so loose that the amount of false matches was simply too high. Then I tried parsing them manually, looking for certain indicators within the strings (e.g. contains square brackets etc.), but this lead to a huge wall of code with way to many special cases and possibilities for a log event to slip through or get falsely identified.

Is there a pattern or technique more suitable to solve a problem like this?

Comment: At first, does something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/DPBBrC/1) fit your needs?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Thank you very much for taking your time and setting up that regex, but unfortunately no, since I just posted an excerpt of the logs where in a full file, there are numerous other possibilities how a line can look and what I need to filter out. While your regex works for the excerpt above, it falsely captured stuff when I checked it against a real exampe. :(

Comment: How many different log messages do you have to deal with?  You may have to bite the bullet and set up a few different database tables for different types and search it in those.  The original message column and then the columns you want to split the information into.  Then you search the message from the log in a LIKE statement i.e. message from table ``PRESSURE STATUS :`` LIKE ``PRESSURE STATUS : Equipment Off`` then split it accordingly into your columns.  I would try to find all of the possible logs and put it into an Excel file and separate them into different tables for your db design...

Comment: @justiceorjustus There are (to my knowledge) around ~2600 possibilities (I threw all log files I got in an script which separated out duplicate lines, excluding the timestamps).

Comment: @artganify Jeez.  I've run into things like this before and also tried to make the "perfect" algorithm to separate them out.  The conditions usually end up fighting one another and giving those false positives.  I'd ended up doing something like my comment above. Sorry that this comment was of no help, it seems like there are too many variables to deal with.

Comment: Can you identify a list of keywords that appear only in one type of message for each message?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Again, unfortunately no. In some cases, the 'keywords' I am looking for are the only ones available (besides some separator character), or there are certain 'keywords' which occur in multiple log events of differnt types (some log events might even contain user comments, which can be literally anything).

Comment: Then it looks like you'll need Harry Potter's help :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Named Capture Groups can help make parsing complex data structures like this.  This example probably doesn't do all you need, but it hopefully serves as a good starting point?  https://regex101.com/r/8oq5lL/1